# Can't set "Anyone" to access to my script

Tags: google-apps-script

I copied an app script on the web that allows people to upload files through a Google Site directly to a folder in my Google Drive, since I'm a teacher, not a programmer.

I followed the instructions set by the programmer, I authorized the app, but when I want to "Deploy as web app", when I get to choose "Who has access to the app:", the only to options available are "Myself" and "anyone within my domain", but "Anyone" is not available.

This is important to me because my students, who are intended to upload files to me, many of them don't have GMail or an account within my same domain. I don't want to make things harder to them by exclusively logging in with another account rahter than their personal e-mail account they use everyday.

I was able to run a very similar script before Google Scripts changed.

Thank you in advance!

```
/* The script is deployed as a web app and renders the form */
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html')
            .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
  // This is important as file upload fail in IFRAME Sandbox mode.
}

/* This function will process the submitted form */
function uploadFiles(form) {

  try {

    /* Name of the Drive folder where the files should be saved */
    var dropbox = form.myName + " " + form.myEmail;
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    /* Find the folder, create if the folder does not exist */
    if (folders.hasNext()) {
          folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    /* Get the file uploaded though the form as a blob */
    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    

     /* Set the file description as the name of the uploader */
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);

    /* Return the download URL of the file once its on Google Drive */
    return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();

  } catch (error) {

    /* If there's an error, show the error message */
    return error.toString();
  }

}
```

Comment: Where is the script file?  Are you creating the script directly on the site through the 'Manage Site' console, or is it hosted in drive?

Answer (score 0):

If you want everyone, even students that are not logged in their Google account when they browse your web-site, have the ability to upload files (=use your script) then you should change `Execute app as` from deployment menu from `user accessing the app` to `Me`, and then you will be able to choose `Anyone, even anonymous`.

The problem is that users, guests that are not logged in Google account are labeled anonymous.

Comment: @ZigMandel , yes, you are probably right considering that `"anyone within my domain"` option, however to achieve the result that he seeks, he will still have to do the actions I've described afterwards. By that I mean setting 'Anyone even anonymous' access.

Comment: yes, he knows that step thus he sees the option "anyone in my domain"

Comment: @ZigMandel , not necessarily, since when you have `Execute as` option set to `User accessing the web-app` there are 2 choices - `Only myself` and `Anyone`, which he actually says.

**when I get to choose "Who has access to the app:", the only to options available are "Myself" and "anyone within my domain", but "Anyone" is not available.** I suppose anyone within my domain option is there since he is actually in domain? group? Nevertheless, it means that he either actually has access banned by Administrator and he will still have to change that option, or he just needs to change that option.

Answer (score 0):

this is because your google apps administrator has restricted access to share drive files with the public. Talk with your admin about it to relax the restriction. I believe the restriction can be set at the organization level so that makes it easier to make an exception for you.